# Why do AES decryption methods take IVs as arguments

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm still new to encryption in general, and I understand why an IV is necessary, but isn't the IV embedded in the encrypted data? Thus, shouldn't any decryption implementation first extract the IV from the data rather than needing to have it supplied?

The reason I assume the IV is embedded in the data is because certain libraries/tools do not require that it be supplied, for instance CryptoJS for JavaScript: `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("U2FsdGVkX1/l3HWODO9GX23rvF0KHmDR6z8XTpYYpe8=", "password").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));`

and openssl: `echo "U2FsdGVkX1++pGg+oWqZbIjccV1NiV2pc1QrQtw0wp4=" | openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -pass pass:password`

and really any actual app that does AES encryption, like TrueCrypt.

Libraries that seem to require the IV:

- mcrypt for PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php
- SymmetricAlgorithm in .Net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79w421xb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

am i getting something confused?

Comment: A *common* *convention* is to prepend the IV onto the start of the encrypted data. That doesn't mean its the only way that the decrypting side can or will obtain IV data, nor that the encrypting side will automatically do that. If you only support reading the IV inline with the encrypted data, then some users may be forced to allocate buffers and copying data around just to satisfy your library that insists that the IV must be at the start of the data.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well... that's a nice answer, in a comment. Care to post it so I can up-vote and take this off the unanswered list?

Comment: @Duncan - I posted the comment whilst trying to decide on a close reason. I still haven't picked one, but it still feels (to me) like it's not a good fit for SO, being as it's more about language/library design.

Comment: Yeah I thought about posting this in Information Security, but I decided I was really asking about the object models which is more of a programming thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the IV may be derived as well. The only reason to include the IV with the ciphertext is when the key is reused for encryption *and* when the IV cannot be derived. It is common but not standardized or required to prefix it if it is present. But that's when you need the IV, so it's the de-facto standard none-the-less.

In your OpenSSL example a random salt is used to generate a key from a password. In that case the salt is different for each encrypt, so the key is random as well. In that case an randomized IV is not needed, although it can (and will be for OpenSSL) derived from the salt and password as well.

Other protocols contain a counter, and in that case a single block encrypt over the counter can be used to create an IV for CBC mode encryption. As long as the counter stays the same at sender/receiver, there is no need to send the IV.

And there are plenty cryptograhic implementations that get it wrong and don't use a random IV for CBC mode. PHP `mcrypt_encrypt` is special in the sense that it even requires an IV for ECB mode, which is then thouroughly ignored as ECB does not use an IV anywhere in the algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand why there would be a "convention" to prepend the IV, thus modifying the actual contents of the data, thus breaking the standard?

Comment: You have to store it somewhere if you cannot regenerate it; which standard would you break? It's not standardized to put it in front, but that does not mean that it is standardized *not* to put it in front.

Comment: I just thought that the standard would cover the actual contents of the encrypted file. I guess it's supposed to be more flexible than that... But to me it seems like it just makes it so one encryption library can't talk to another, which would be the point of having standards in the first place...

Comment: If you want to have standard message format, use CMS, PGP or XML encryption. Of course, not every language/runtime has support for those, but the standards are in place. It's just the low level encryption schemes without container format that suffer from these kind of issues.

Comment: having explored this further, my problem was that i did not understand that since AES is fast, a password (that i can remember) will never have enough entropy to not be solved with brute force. so while my question was a programming question, my problem was an information security/cryptography one.

Comment: Glad you seem to understand that now...that's pretty important to realize :)